# Dynamic breadcrumbs from nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic, breadcrumbs

I have recreated my problem in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-northcutt-7c9sr

I am struggling with logic on how to make dynamic breadcrumbs. My project is a catalog with furniture. A user selects from dropdown menu category that he needs. The result is a list of furniture. On that page, I need to make breadcrumbs. I have nested array of objects which goes 5-6 levels deep. I don't know how to loop thru this array.

When a user clicks on the menu I'm saving all indexes and then rendering items. The problem is don't know how to use these indexes to make breadcrumbs

[image]

From this array, I need to make breadcrumbs

[image]

Any direction or help is appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to do this code?

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with recursive function

```
const getPath = (data, [{ key, index } = {}, ...rest]=[], tempStore = []) => {
    if (key in data) {
      const obj = data[key][index];
      tempStore.push(obj)
      let breadcrumb = [obj.name, ...getPath(obj, rest, tempStore)];
      return breadcrumb
    }
    if (!rest.length) {
      setBreadcrumbData(tempStore) // useState hook
    }
    return [];
  }
```

Comment: what does setBreadcrumbData(tempStore), or is some method missing?

Comment: It's Usestate hook

Comment: it is possible that from a complete example?